# can someone help to interpret ACF and PACF graph?

Tags: time-series, bitcoin, autocorrelation

can someone help to interpret ACF and PACF graph?

in the graphs, I don't see any decay. am I right about that assumption
other than that what can I comment about both?
the data plotted is squared daily return of bitcoin
[image]
[image]
thanks in advance

enter image description here

Comment: Hi @ Sarthak Gurnani. May I ask what type of interpretation you're looking for? Typically ACF/PACFs are used as part of the Box-Jenkins method of fitting your model. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your comment and yes that’s exactly what im looking for! 

Would appreciate your help